# Apply upload file plugin to jQueryUI button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, file-upload

I wish to use a jQueryUI dialog button to upload a file.  For instance, consider the following dialog.

```
$('#myDialog').dialog({
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'Upload File',
            click: function() {
                //Open file prompt to allow user to upload a file
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Most file upload plugins I see are implemented by applying the plugin directly to an element ID.

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({...});

var uploader = new ss.SimpleUpload({
      button: 'fileupload', // HTML element used as upload button
      ...
});
```

How is this accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe?

```
var uploader=$('<input/>',{type:'file'}).hide().fileupload({
    url: settings.upload_path,
})

$('#myDialog').dialog({
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'File',
            click: function() {
                uploader.trigger('click');
            }
        },
    ]
});
```